# Is a buck converter less efficient than 2 seperate PSUs?

Tags: power-supply, buck, efficiency

I've built a CNC machine that runs from a 24V 400W PSU (Spindle & Electronics)
I just bought a laser to attach to it that requires 12V.

As I'd never run the spindle and laser at the same time, there's plenty of power available for the laser.

Am I better off using a buck converter to get down to 12V?
Or just buying a whole new 12V PSU just for the laser?

A buck converter is cheaper and smaller, but which solution would use the least power taking into account buck converter probably only about %80 efficient.

Comment: Best way to install double output PSU.

Comment: If you are able to turn off the 24 volt supply when not in use, probably more efficient to get a 12 V AC-DC converter. But if you are going to just leave the 24 V supply on anyway, I would say just get a buck converter. Try to find an efficient one.

Comment: Just in case you haven't done so already, remember to get a fume extraction system and enclosure for your laser. I know there are ads showing people laser cutting with an exposed system wearing (probably not properly rated) safety glasses, but unless you're only doing low power stuff for a short amount of time that's really not a good idea. At least get a set of safety glasses from a reputable manufacturer rated for your laser wavelength, do not trust the ones in the box if it's a no-name brand from China.

Comment: The power levels involved are so low (less than 50W in use, and I assume you turn it off when not using) that efficiency concerns are not particularly significant. Makes more sense to think what is easier to implement safely and so that it is easy to use. E.g. you'll want some way to ensure the laser diode stays off when your enclosure is open.

Answer (score 4):

If you're switching the input to each supply individually, nothing is more efficient than a power supply that's disconnected dissipating zero power when zero is required.  As opposed to having one always-on, plus a secondary converter that either draws some idle power (or can be disabled too, most converters have this feature) or costs its own efficiency.

Bucks can be efficient enough that you might not care, compared to the somewhat lower efficiency of offline PSUs.

I might prefer the buck converter, because I'm using the 24V for other things, so that PSU needs to be always-on anyway, and the efficiency cost can be small.  (Be careful using cheap modules; they may have poor performance, not to mention horrendous EMI that might bother even a CNC system.)  I don't know if this will be true of your system as well.

Answer (score 1):

The PSUs are also going to contain buck converters (or some other type of DC-DC converter) in them.

So the question isn't really well-formed.

Depending on the current levels and step-down ratio, buck converters can be much more than 80% efficient, though. 90% isn't too hard to achieve, and you can get over 95% with good design.